# I want to add a new tag to Wordpress URL permastruct

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, tags

I installed a TV SHOW plugin on my WordPress install. URLs are like this:

https://www.mywebsite.com/tv-show/title-of-tvshow

Now I would like to add a specific tag to redirect the user to the right TV show season like this:

https://www.mywebsite.com/tv-show/title-of-tvshow/season/3

This code doesn't seem to work and creates a new set of URLs instead of adding the new `%season%` tag to the plugin existing permalink structure

```php
       global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag('%tv-show%', '([^/]+)', 'tv_show=');
        $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag('%season%','([^&]+)', 'season=');
        $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('tv-show', '/tv-show/%tv-show%/%season/');

        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
```

Comment: Which TV Show plugin did you install? Not sure why you're calling `$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag` instead of `add_rewrite_tag`, but this might help: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_tag/#comment-1829 Additionally, how/where are you trying to use those tags? **Keep in mind 3rd party plugin support is offtopic on WPSE**